# Python SSL Socket Client Authentification

Tags: python, ssl, certificate

I'm trying to set up a server and client in python where the server authenticates clients using SSL with certificates. There are a lot of examples of SSL certificates online, but everything I've found has the server providing a certificate to the client and the client checking it. I need the server to ensure that the client has the authority to connect to the server. I understand how to generate and send certificates and the basics of how they work. I would type out my code, but my client/server without SSL is working fine and I've been referencing [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html) for SSL. The client/server example at the bottom of that page summarizes my understanding of SSL certs in python.

I realize this isn't much to go on, but if someone could explain the basic modifications to that example to have the server authenticate the client instead of the other way around, that would be awesome. Alternatively, a link to an example or even just some socket methods to investigate would be very helpful. Let me know if more information is needed. I don't mean to be vague and promise I've spent all morning looking for info myself :).

Edit: I'm trying to stick to the basic ssl library. Aka "import ssl".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use [SSLSocket.getpeercert](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLSocket.getpeercert) to get the certificate. The client would need to specify a key and certificate when wrapping the socket just like the server side. On the server side, you will also need to pass ca_certs="path_to_ca_cert_file" and probably also want to specify cert_reqs=CERT_REQUIRED (see. args for [ssl.wrap_socket](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl.wrap_socket).

In addition to this, it sounds like you might be looking to do certificate based client authentication/authorization? This is a simple matter of using getpeercert to get the client certificate and accessing fields within the certificate to use in a normal authentication path (i.e. Common Name == User Id)

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what your question refers, however you can see [SSL in Python](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2008/10/14/ssl-in-python-26/), [other resource for SSL in Python](http://bobthegnome.blogspot.ro/2007/08/making-ssl-connection-in-python.html), [Validating SSL](http://techtonik.rainforce.org/2010/11/validating-ssl-server-certificate-with.html), [get SSL Certificate information](http://phreakmonkey.com/index.php/archives/100) and you probably found other good links.

Comment: It's my understanding that the code in the example I linked has the server send the client its certificate. The client then checks the cert against its chain of certs to maker sure the server is ok to connect to. I need to do the opposite. I need the client to send the server its cert, have the server check the client's cert against its list of allowed, and finally complete the handshake with the client. I'll keep reading...maybe I don't understand as much as I thought. Thanks for the links.